# autocomplete textview updating the list for it through another api not googleapi

Tags: android, listview, autocomplete, adapter

I am having trouble with Autocomplete Textview where I am calling the list for it through an API 
this is the code that  I am using for Adapter of the list
class PickDropLocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList PickDropBeans, temppickDropBean, suggestions;

```
public PickDropLocationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PickDropBean> objects) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
    this.PickDropBeans = objects;
    this.temppickDropBean = new ArrayList<PickDropBean>(objects);
    this.suggestions = new ArrayList<PickDropBean>(objects);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PickDropBean PickDropBean = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_pick_drop, parent, false);
    }
    TextView txtpickDropBean = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomer);
    ImageView ivpickDropBeanImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCustomerImage);
    if (txtpickDropBean != null)
        txtpickDropBean.setText(PickDropBean.getLocationname() );
    /*if (ivpickDropBeanImage != null && PickDropBean.getProfilePic() != -1)
        ivpickDropBeanImage.setImageResource(PickDropBean.getProfilePic());*/
    // Now assign alternate color for rows
```

//        if (position % 2 == 0)
//            convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.odd));
//        else
//            convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.even));

```
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return myFilter;
}

Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        PickDropBean PickDropBean = (PickDropBean) resultValue;
        return PickDropBean.getLocationname() ;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            suggestions.clear();
            for (PickDropBean people : temppickDropBean) {
                if (people.getLocationname().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    suggestions.add(people);
                }
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayList<PickDropBean> c = (ArrayList<PickDropBean>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (PickDropBean cust : c) {
                add(cust);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

}

And the Volley is used for calling the API within which I am parsing my JSON object through API and then setting the list and the adapter 
error is 
ava.lang.NullPointerException: collection == null
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: it is giving me null pointer exception